# Blazor WebAssembly Dev Express Data Grid - Load All Rows without Pagination

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-gridcontrol, devexpress-blazor

I started experimenting with devexpress Blazor Grid component for a project that we are migrating from Webforms to Blazor WebAssembly.
I see the pagination component in the grid works really fine.
But I have this requirement to load all records without pagination and kind of struggling to get the right settings

```
<DxDataGrid DataAsync="@GetEmployeeStatssAsync" WIDTH="700px"     VerticalScrollBarMode="ScrollBarMode.Auto" 
VerticalScrollableHeight="200">
<DxDataGridColumn Field="@nameof(EmployeeStatResponse.FullName)" Width="30px"  />
<DxDataGridColumn Field="@nameof(EmployeeStatResponse.Batches)" Width="30px" />
<DxDataGridColumn Field="@nameof(EmployeeStatResponse.Lines)" Width="20px" />
<DxDataGridColumn Field="@nameof(EmployeeStatResponse.Units)"  Width="20px" />
<DxDataGridColumn Field="@nameof(EmployeeStatResponse.Hours)"  Width="30px" />
<DxDataGridColumn Field="@nameof(EmployeeStatResponse.LPH)"  Width="30px" />
<DxDataGridColumn Field="@nameof(EmployeeStatResponse.Errors)"  Width="30px" />
<DxDataGridColumn Field="@nameof(EmployeeStatResponse.EPer)"  Width="30px" />
</DxDataGrid>
```

I tried by setting the **pagesize** as 10,000, But when I do that **the screen freezes.**

```
<DxDataGrid DataAsync="@GetEmployeeStatssAsync(51)" WIDTH="700px" PageSize="10000"
            VerticalScrollBarMode="ScrollBarMode.Auto" 
            VerticalScrollableHeight="200">
```

Please let me know what is the correct wat to implement

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ShowPager, PagerAllDataRowsItemVisible, PageSize properties for DxDataGrid

```
<DxDataGrid Data="@employees" ShowPager="false" PagerAllDataRowsItemVisible="false" PageSize="10000">
        <DxDataGridColumn Field="Id" AllowSort="false" Width="50px"/>
        <DxDataGridColumn Field="Name" AllowSort="false" Width="50px"/>
        <DxDataGridColumn Field="PhoneNumber" AllowSort="false" Width="50px"/>
</DxDataGrid>
```